# How can I match up URL encoding (or perhaps charset) between javascript and server sides of my application?

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, url-encoding

I have a file uploaded via PHP to a server.

The file name is tânia.jpg.

At the front end of my web application (which has the encoding set to UTF8) Javascript fetches Tânia's name from an API and writes it to the page, then tries to fetch her avatar by creating an image in the DOM with src = "tânia.jpg".

This results in a 404 error.

Observing the network traffic, I found that the result of the Javascript DOM addition is a failed call to myserver.com/t%C3%A2nia.jpg whereas in order to successfully retrieve the file I need to call myserver.com/ta%CC%82nia.jpg.

Can anyone advise me what the source of such a problem would be? Is it a character set discrepancy between the API or browser and the server? How can I resolve the difference?